# Static inline members initialization order

Tags: c++, c++17, static-initialization

A well known problem in C++ is the [static initialization order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order). Is it still considered a problem when one use *C++17 static inline members*?

Here an example where a static inline member is used in two different translation units (a.cpp and b.cpp) as an initializer for two non-inline static members:

**counter.hh**

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

class Counter
{
    public:
        Counter()  { std::ofstream os("o.txt", std::ofstream::app); os << "Counter created" << std::endl; }
        ~Counter() { std::ofstream os("o.txt", std::ofstream::app); os << "Counter destroyed" << std::endl; }
        void add_instance()    
        { 
            ++m_instances; 
            std::ofstream os("o.txt", std::ofstream::app); os << "Counter increased: " << m_instances << std::endl; 
        }
        void remove_instance() 
        { 
            --m_instances; 
            std::ofstream os("o.txt", std::ofstream::app); os << "Counter decreased: " << m_instances << std::endl; 
        }

    private:
        int m_instances = 0;
};

class Object
{
    public:
        Object(Counter & counter) : m_counter(counter) 
        {
            m_counter.add_instance(); 
            std::ofstream os("o.txt", std::ofstream::app); os << "Object created" << std::endl; 
        }
        ~Object() 
        { 
            m_counter.remove_instance(); 
            std::ofstream os("o.txt", std::ofstream::app); os << "Object destroyed" << std::endl; 
        }

    private:
        Counter & m_counter;
};

struct C
{
    static inline Counter static_counter{};
};
```

**a.hh**

```
#pragma once

#include "counter.hh"

struct A
{
    static Object static_a; //not inline
};
```

**a.cpp**

```
#include "a.hh"

Object A::static_a{C::static_counter};
```

**b.hh**

```
#pragma once

#include "counter.hh"

struct B
{
    static Object static_b; //not inline
};
```

**b.cpp**

```
#include "b.hh"

Object B::static_b{C::static_counter};
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "a.hh"
#include "b.hh"

int main() { }
```

*output (with MSVC 16.1.2)*

```
Counter created
Counter increased: 1
Object created
Counter increased: 2
Object created
Counter decreased: 1
Object destroyed
Counter decreased: 0
Object destroyed
Counter destroyed
```

I think that, with regard to the initialization, this practice is safe because the C++17 standard ensures that static inline members are: (1) always initialized before any use and (2) initialized only once across multiple translation units.

But I'd like to know if there are any hidden downsides in this pattern, for example related to the order of destruction of each variable across different TUs. Is it well-defined that both `static_a` and `static_b` are always destroyed before `static_counter`?

Comment: As much as I know, the destruction's order, is the opposite to the creation order. In this case, it depends on your include's order. A.hpp, include counter.hpp, so the initialize order is: Counter, A, B, And the destruction's order is: B, A, Counter. I am almost sure about that, so let's wait for someone official answer.

Comment: Maybe you are right that the destruction order is always the opposite to the creation order. But there is no guarantee that the order is Counter, A, B. It could also be Counter, B, A.  It does not depend on the inclusion order, because we have three different translation units (a.cpp, b.cpp and main.cpp) and how can you say that the variables in main.cpp have a priority over those in a.cpp? I think it's implementation-defined, or completely random at all.

Comment: What do you mean by safe? value of a/b are not predictable...

Comment: What I’d like to understand is if `static_counter` is guaranteed to be initialized before `static_a`/`static_b` and if it’s guaranteed to be destroyed after `static_a`/`static_b`. I know that `static_a` and `static_b` would be dangerous if used to initialize other static members, but I’m only interested in the relation between `static_counter` and other global variables that depend on it for construction. Maybe I should find a clearer example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is fine, since in every translation unit `static_counter` is [defined before](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization#Dynamic_initialization) `static_a`/`static_b`.  Destruction order is not guaranteed to be the reverse (given threads, this is meaningless anyway), but the [reverse of each guarantee holds](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit), so that works too.

Comment: Thanks, I think you are referring to the paragraphs *Dynamic Initalization - 2)* in the first page and *1) - b)* in the second page.

Comment: @Tarquiscani: That’s correct (it’s 1a before C++11 for destructors, if anyone cares).